# find and append in column by using regular expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the one table named test. I need to find any alphabet and append with ALL in the name column by using regular expression. Please need your inputs.

Notes: in future values also will be inserted into that column. So in runtime it should replace.

```
create table test(id number, name varchar2(10));
insert INTO TEST VALUES (1,'_A');
insert INTO TEST VALUES (2,'_F');
insert INTO TEST VALUES (3,'_K');
insert INTO TEST VALUES (4,'_B || _G');
```

My output should be like below

```
-------------------------------
  id    column
--------------------------------
    1   _AALL
    2   _FALL
    3   _KALL
    4   _BALL || _GALL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `regexp_replace`

```
with test as(
  select 1 as id , '_A' as l from dual union all
  select 1 as id , '_B || _G' as l from dual 
)

select t.*
      , trim(regexp_replace(t.l,'(_[A-Z])( |$)','\1'||'ALL '))
  from test t
```

Comment: A optimalization in this would be checken for || in the string before doing a regex as using regex is not cheap.. the record which does not contain a || you can simple string concat..

Answer (score 0):

```
with test as(
  select 1 as id , '_A' as l from dual union all
  select 1 as id , '_B || _G' as l from dual 
)
select t.*,
regexp_replace(t.l,'([A-Z])','\1'||'ALL') rps
from test t;

        ID L                    RPS                 
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 _A                   _AALL               
         1 _B || _G             _BALL || _GALL
```